# When do I use 'of' after 'little', 'some', and 'lots' and when can I omit it?

Tags: prepositions, usage

I think most of these sentences are correct:

1. A little bit of bread.
2. A little of bread. (Is this correct?)
3. A little of that.
4. A little time gone.
5. Some of that bread.
6. Some people.
7. Lots of work.
8. A lot of work.
9. Lots more.

If so, when do I use *of* after those words? (little, some, lots)

Comment: No. 2 does not need "of". I can't really explain why though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation I found [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/quantifiers/little-a-little-few-a-few) seems alright.

> We use of with (a) little and (a) few when they come before articles (a/an, the), demonstratives (this, that), possessives (my, your) or pronouns (him, them):
>
> *Put the flour into a bowl, blend with a little of the milk, beat in the egg yolks, then the sugar and the rest of the milk.*
>
> *A few of his films were seen abroad.*

All the sentences except 2 are correct.

*A little bit of bread* is fine because here, *little* describes *bit of bread*.  *Of* has nothing to do with *little*. You say, *a bit of something* and *a little bit of something*.

*A little of bread* sounds unnatural. You could say *a little bread* or *a little bit of bread* instead.